# X rows affected, but NO rows value changed

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with MySQL. When I run the code below, via **phpmyadmin**, it returns `9000 rows affected`, and if I make a search, shows that it replaced all the needed things successfully. But if I go and hit `EDIT` option (in *phpmyadmin*) on one of the records/rows inside "`post_content`" column no changes are done inside it, everything stays the same. What might be the reason?

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
    SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'31.media.tumblr.com/','41.media.tumblr.com/') 
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
    AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';
```

for me there's something wrong with the code above. maybe it returns null or something and stops the update... Because it does change things, for real, if I remove the `AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';` part.

Database is a default WordPress one / http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/1407938242wordpress-database.png & http://images.devshed.com/sc/stories/.CodexM/pdfphp1.jpg

example of data inside post_content:

```
<p>some text</p>
<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif" alt="" />
<img src="http://11.media.tumblr.com/L4B1q/tumblr_ml5i2cGL4B1qz4fjqo1.gif" alt="" />
other text
<img src="http://51.media.tumblr.com/n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1/tumblr_n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1.jpg" alt="" />
some other text

...
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you edit a row inside phpMyAdmin using the Edit option on that row it does not save the change? Or do you mean something else by "open/edit"?

Comment: I mean using the EDIT option

Comment: When you edit a record in phpMyAdmin and submit the change it will display the SQL statement it used for that edit operation. Please update your post with the SQL that phpMyAdmin tried to execute. That should tell us where its failing.

Comment: My problem is with the SQL code I posted above... not with the EDIT option in phpmyadmin.

Comment: ahh, you're saying that executing the code above "looks" like it performed the edit, but when you open a record to view it you see that the changes from the UPDATE really were NOT performed?

Comment: You also say that if you "make a search" you can see that everything is ok. How do you make that search?

Comment: @davidethell exactly!

Comment: @Aioros I go to "SEARCH in DataBase" put %31.media.tumblr.com/% find  all words inside table post_content and it returns 0 matches (all this via phpmyadmin)

Comment: If I go and check the content in WordPress backend (edit post) it also displays that nothing was changed!!!!

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask: are you sure you're not looking at two different databases somehow?

Comment: nope. because if I go and change it manually changes are visible in frondend etc. plus I've tested both locally and on a live servers.. same thing happens on both.

Comment: for me there's something wrong with the code in question. maybe it returns  null or something and stops the update... Because it does change things, for real, if I remove the `AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';` part

Comment: That's both weird and relevant, I'd suggest adding it to the question.